# submit and upload file on IE8 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, form-submit

It works on other browsers but not for IE:

javascript:

```
function getFile(){
    document.getElementById("upfile").click();    
}

function sub(){
    document.getElementById("myf").submit();
}
```

body:

```
   <div id="yourBtn" onclick="getFile()">Upload File<img src="img/upload.jpg></div>


  <iframe name="upload_iframe" src="upload_file.php" style="display:block;"></iframe>

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="upload_file.php" name="myForm" id="myf" target="upload_iframe">
   <input id="upfile"  type="file" name="file" value="" onchange="sub(this)" />
</form>
```

I know that there are a lot of ways to submit form (I used jQuery as well) but it still doesn't work on IE8 and I don't know why. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Do the functions get called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Submit() Access denied IFrame IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482265/js-submit-access-denied-iframe-ie)

Comment: here your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396411/ie-javascript-form-submit-with-file-input