# Access is denied error in signalr script while using iframes in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-domain

I am rendering report inside an iframe and their domains are not same. While rendering I am getting 'Access is denied' error in IE. Works fine in other browers.

Jquery version: 1.10.2
Signalr version: 2.1.2

**Note:** Tried by upgrading signalr to 2.2.2 also. It is not working.

```
//Signalr scripts goes here
    <script>
            $(document.ready(function () {
                var response = $.connection.signalrHub;
                response.client.connection = function () {
                   //connection
                };
                SJ.iwc.SignalR.start();
            });
    </script>
```

[image]

**Solution tried:**

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] });
```

Tried by adding this inside `document.ready` but not working.

Anyone faced this issue ? Is there is any work around for this ?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886547/access-is-denied-javascript-error-when-trying-to-access-the-document-object-of

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following steps in your sample project.
1. Try to upgrade to jQuery latest version.
2. Try to set the cross domain support using $.support.cors = true.