# Powerbi embedding works in chrome but not in IE11

Tags: javascript, powerbi, extjs5, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to embedd an simple powerbi report in Extjs5. i got embedtoken and embedurl. it fails while loading report in Div.
I added https://*microsoft.com and https://api.powerbi.com as trusted sites in IE but didnt help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFXSW.png)

Error:

Exception was thrown at line 1778, column 335 in https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.12816.311/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

Note: reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js is a dynamic script file.

Comment: Probably somewhat similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886547/access-is-denied-javascript-error-when-trying-to-access-the-document-object-of

Comment: Oficcially, IE11 is still [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-browsers), but not for all features. And every day it will get worse. Try to explain this to the users and stop using IE at all. It's dead for years anyway.