# Using Blob urls for src in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We're creating `<iframe>`s dynamically (e.g. for a rich text editor or a debug window) and injecting html into the `src`. For years we used a `javascript:` url as the `src` similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1739572/1168892) until we ran into same-origin-policy issues with multiple independent iframes.

Our current solution is creating an object url for a blob that contains the html:

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  , html = '<h1>it works!</h1>'
  , blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'})
  , url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

iframe.src = url;
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(iframe);
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE11 (for browsers where `URL` or `Blob` are undefined we fallback to the `javascript:` solution). IE11 raises [`SCRIPT5`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn887953(v=vs.94).aspx)`: Access is denied`.

*Are we misusing the APIs? Is there a special API for IE? A known workaround?*

Comment: damn your issue is hard to figure out! I've changed the Security settings of my IE11 to the lowest possible config and I've sandboxed the iframe (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/) still the code snippet didn't work! There is one IE bug that I saw related to this which had no update whatsoever (https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/797361/ie-10-treats-blob-url-as-cross-origin-and-denies-access) Apparently, IE is seeing this as an XSS even though its a Blob URL...i don't think there's anything wrong with the API as Blobs are supported in IE11

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately IE [does not support DATA URI's](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)*with a few caveats. I have the same issue, but with a PDF in an embedded tag.

It looks like you can use [msSaveOrOpenblob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772332(v=vs.85).aspx) to have IE open your blob file

Comment: We came across `msSaveOrOpenBlob` as well, but it actually does not do what we want. Called with the blob url, it will open this "do you want to open or save this file?" dialog/notification. But we want the iframe to use the blob url as its src.

Comment: To my knowledge it cannot be done in IE11 for html templates like what you are doing. A work around if you are using some sort of server side language is to have the src directly point to a service that returns your markup.

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 does not support all the Data URI's.

It supports only images and linked resources like CSS or JS. Please note HTML files are not supported.